# how to fetch data from dataset to gridview ?

Tags: c#, mysql, gridview

```
 private void BrokerWiseSalesReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            ds = null;
            dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
            ds = GetBrokerDetailspageload();
            //int ii = 0;            
            if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
            {


                dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];  
             }
         }
```

In Dataset[ `if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)`] I am getting the No of rows but 
   while storing in `gridview` using the statement

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

i am Getting no of rows as null

I am using c# connecting with Mysql

Only thing is m Not able to store the data in gridview from dataset

The which m using to store the data set data to gridview is right?
just guide me

```
dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
```

Comment: Can you debug on your line where ds gets your data? I think it may not be receiving any data.

Comment: No Ds gets the data properly but the data is not storing in the gridview .......

Comment: Is it actually reaching your line "dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];" ?

Comment: { ds.Tables[0];}  here I am getting 29 records but in this    dataGridView1.DataSource  i am Null Records

Comment: But is it actually reaching your line? Set a breakpoint on  dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0] and debug, see if your program reaches the line.

Comment: Yes it reaches the line properly but in dataGridview1.DataSource gets null value that the problem

Answer (score 1):

You need to use MySqlDataAdapter.

```
private void BrokerWiseSalesReport_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
    {
        DataSet ds = new DataSet();
        ds = null;
        dataGridView1.Rows.Clear();
        ds = GetBrokerDetailspageload();
        MySqlDataAdapter msd= new MySqlDataAdapter();
        msd.Fill(ds);
        //int ii = 0;            
        //if (ds.Tables[0].Rows.Count != 0)
       // {


            dataGridView1.DataSource = ds;
        // }
     }
```

Please let me know the further issues.

**Update**

```
 public DataSet GetBrokerDetailspageload()
 {
    MySqlConnection mycon=new MySqlConnection("Your connection string");
    string str = "SELECT sm.BrokerName,st.ID,sm.SalesCode,sm.BillNo,sm.SalesBy,st.ProductName,st.Quantity,st.SalesRate,st.Net‌​Weight,st.Expense,st.Amount,st.VatP,St.VatAmt FROM salesmaster sm INNER JOIN salestransaction st ON sm.SalesCode=st.SalesCode";
    MySqlCommand cmd=new MySqlCommand(str,mycon);
    DataSet ds=new DataSet();
    MySqlDataAdapter da = new MySqlDataAdapter(cmd);
    da.Fill(ds);
    return ds;
 }
 private void BrokerWiseSalesReport_Load()
 {
     DataSet ds = new DataSet();
     ds = null;
     ds=GetBrokerDetailspageload();
     dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];
 }
```

Comment: Getting Error Message Like this

Comment: Error 4 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' does not contain a definition for 'DataBind' and no extension method 'DataBind' accepting a first argument of type 'System.Windows.Forms.DataGridView' could be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference?)

Comment: same Error I am getting

Comment: Can you show us the GetBrokerDetailspageload() code ?. So that, we can clarify it quickly.

Comment: public DataSet GetBrokerDetailspageload()
        {
            
            string str = "SELECT sm.BrokerName,st.ID, sm.SalesCode,sm.BillNo,sm.SalesBy,st.ProductName,st.Quantity,st.SalesRate,st.NetWeight,st.Expense,st.Amount,st.VatP,St.VatAmt FROM salesmaster sm INNER JOIN salestransaction st ON sm.SalesCode=st.SalesCode";
            objStmt.Stmt = str;
            DataSet ds = objStmt.CallQuery(objStmt);
            return ds;
        }

Comment: Check my updated part. I worked with the above code, and it works fine. So go ahead with my code. It will work for you.And let me know the result.

Answer (score 0):

I think you are missing one line of code.

Add this line after dataGridView1.DataSource = ds.Tables[0];

```
dataGridView1.DataBind();
```